# Is it Possible to Pass Vector Rather than a Class Label in the Dataset

Tags: object-detection-api

When writing the TFRecords for the object detection API we have to include the field `image/object/class/label` to give the list of labels corresponding to each bounding box.

Is there any way to pass a vector instead of the integer label?

The reason I ask is that the labels I'm trying to encode have a hierarchical nature, and I'm interested in trying to capture in a label vector and see what effect that has on the training.

For instance let's say I was detecting cars, vans, mopeds and motorbikes. If I was to label a motorbike bounding, rather than passing `3` as the label, I might want to use the vector `[0, 0, 0.33, 1.0]` so as not to "punish" motorbike and moped confusion, as much as motorbike -> car confusion.

If it's not possible to encode the labels as vectors, I would be interested to hear if there are any other possible solutions to the scenario I outlined